# Publish test result fails for VSTest in Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, vstest

I have added the below steps to run unit test in Azure pipelines for React UI.

1. Added a file where package.json file resides:
   File name:jestTrxProcessor.js.js
   The content:

```js
var builder = require("jest-trx-results-processor/dist/testResultsProcessor"); 
var builder = require("jest-trx-results-processor");
 
var processor = builder({
  outputFile: "jestTestresults.trx", 
});
 
module.exports = processor;
```

2. In package.json I entered the below code:

```js
 "scripts": {
....
"test": "jest"
},
devdependencies{
 ...
 "jest": "^23.4.1",
  "jest-trx-results-processor": "0.0.7",
  "jsdom": "^11.12.0"
},
"jest": {
       "testResultsProcessor": "./jestTrxProcessor.js",
    "reporters": [
"default",
[
  "jest-trx-results-processor",
  {
    "outputFile": "./jestTrxProcessor.js",
  
  }
]]},
```

4.In the yaml file I added the below script:

```js
 script: |
    npm install
    npm run build
    npm install jest-trx-results-processor --save-dev
    yarn add --dev jest-trx-results-processor
    npm run test
  displayName: 'npm install and build'
  
- task: PublishTestResults@2
  inputs:
    testResultsFormat: 'VSTest'
    testResultsFiles: './jestTrxProcessor.js'
    testRunTitle: 'FrontEnd Test'
```

I am getting the below error once I run the pipeline in Azure Devops:

> No tests found
> In /home/vsts/work/1/s
> 40 files checked.
> testMatch: **/**tests**/**/*.js?(x),**/?(*.)+(spec|test).js?(x) - 0 matches
> testPathIgnorePatterns: /node_modules/ - 40 matches

I have searched for this folder and its no where created/exists. I am not getting what am I missing here.
I am quite new to creation of yaml pipeline for react UI.
Kindly help.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> No tests found In /home/vsts/work/1/s 40 files checked. testMatch: /tests//.js?(x),**/?(.)+(spec|test).js?(x) - 0 matches testPathIgnorePatterns: /node_modules/ - 40 matches

Based on the error message, the jest test is finding the xx.js file under the `__tests__` folder.  This is due to the default testmatch rule.

I could reproduce this issue.

[image]

To solve this issue, you need to change the following settings:

1. Change the name of the folder where the xxx.js file is located to `__tests__` .

[image]

2.Edit the  **testResultsProcessor** path in package.json.

Here is an example:

```
 "jest": {
     "testResultsProcessor": "./__tests__/jestTrxProcessor", 
  "reporters": [
    "default",
    [
      "jest-trx-results-processor",
      {
        "outputFile": "relative/path/to/resulting.trx"
       
      }
    ]
  ]


  }
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: It partially fixed the error it seems but with new error:                                                    
 Failed to parse result files: System.Xml.XmlException: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.

Comment: After change the folder name, can you see the tests are running? For the new issue, it  is not same as the orginal one in the Question. Could you please update the question or create a new question about this new issue? This will be helpful to solve this issue.

Comment: Sure . I will create a new question then. Thank you